# Convert and map data to chart understandable format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert this data

```
var data = [{
    "Country": "World",
    "Source": "Electricity",
    "Year": "2022",
    "Value": "20.0000"
  },
  {
    "Country": "World",
    "Source": "Gas",
    "Year": "2022",
    "Value": "30.0000"
  },
  {
    "Country": "World",
    "Source": "Hydrogen",
    "Year": "2022",
    "Value": "40.0000"
  },
  {
    "Country": "World",
    "Source": "Oil",
    "Year": "2022",
    "Value": "50.0000"
  },
  {
    "Country": "World",
    "Source": "Renewables",
    "Year": "2022",
    "Value": "60.0000"
  },{
    "Country": "World",
    "Source": "Renewables",
    "Year": "2021",
    "Value": "50.0000"
  }
];
```

to this format

```
[{
  name: 'Renewables',
  data: [60.0000, 50.0000]
}, {
  name: 'Oil',
  data: [50.0000]
},{
  name: 'Hydrogen',
  data: [40.0000]
}, {
  name: 'Gas',
  data: [30.0000]
}, {
  name: 'Electricity',
  data: [20.0000]
}]
```

how can I do that?

Any Suggestion please

Code I have done

```
 for (let index = 0; index < uniqueSources.length; index++) {
      var arrSmall = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < this.ResponseToShow.length; j++) {
        if (uniqueSources[index] == this.ResponseToShow[j]['Source']) {
          arrSmall.push(Number(this.ResponseToShow[j]['Value']));
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(arrSmall);
```

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: The conversion could be done by a map https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map which still leaves the ticky part of parsing the same data (ex. Renewables) for different years. Since it looks like you also want it sorted, you can add https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

That being said, please show the code you have so far, as we're not here to write code for you but help you out where you're stuck. To help us help you, please provide what exactly you want, not just input/output data to guess

Comment: @Andy, I don't know how to implement that's why I have asked this question...

Comment: @wawa, I know maping and reducing fundamentals of javascript but don't know how to convert this data to the format i want...

Comment: using `.map` you could use `console.log(data.map(x => { name: x.source, data: parseInt(x.value) }));` next you'd need to implement the logic to combine the entries (using reduce) if their name matches and then finally do a `.sort` on them. Does this help?

Comment: @wawa, bro I know `mapping` and `reducing`  concept. the thing I wanted is the way to use the `reduce` in this functionality. btw thanks for the suggestion. i appreciate your time. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common use case of `reduce`

```js
var data = [{
    "Country": "World",
    "Source": "Electricity",
    "Year": "2022",
    "Value": "20.0000"
  },
  {
    "Country": "World",
    "Source": "Gas",
    "Year": "2022",
    "Value": "30.0000"
  },
  {
    "Country": "World",
    "Source": "Hydrogen",
    "Year": "2022",
    "Value": "40.0000"
  },
  {
    "Country": "World",
    "Source": "Oil",
    "Year": "2022",
    "Value": "50.0000"
  },
  {
    "Country": "World",
    "Source": "Renewables",
    "Year": "2022",
    "Value": "60.0000"
  },{
    "Country": "World",
    "Source": "Renewables",
    "Year": "2021",
    "Value": "50.0000"
  }
];

let res = Object.values(data.reduce((acc,curr) => {
    if(!acc[curr.Source]){
    acc[curr.Source] = {name: curr.Source,data: []}
  }
  
  acc[curr.Source]['data'].push(curr.Value)
  return acc;
},{}))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [`.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and [`.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) to achieve this. Try this

```js
var data = [
  {
    "Country": "World",
    "Source": "Electricity",
    "Year": "2022",
    "Value": "20.0000"
  },
  {
    "Country": "World",
    "Source": "Gas",
    "Year": "2022",
    "Value": "30.0000"
  },
  {
    "Country": "World",
    "Source": "Hydrogen",
    "Year": "2022",
    "Value": "40.0000"
  },
  {
    "Country": "World",
    "Source": "Oil",
    "Year": "2022",
    "Value": "50.0000"
  },
  {
    "Country": "World",
    "Source": "Renewables",
    "Year": "2022",
    "Value": "60.0000"
  },{
    "Country": "World",
    "Source": "Renewables",
    "Year": "2021",
    "Value": "50.0000"
  }
];

let fdata = []; // formatted data
data.forEach(({Source, Value}) => {
    let index = fdata.findIndex(o => o.name === Source); // check if Source exist
    if( index === -1 ){
        fdata.push({name: Source, data: [Value]});
    }else{
        fdata[index].data.push(Value);
    }
});

fdata = fdata.reverse(); // to reverse the order

console.log(fdata)
```